# Get attributes of sending link in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Razor form that has multiple links that call to an action and I'm trying to condense the jQuery.  The links are as such:

```
<a id="approveModal" 
   href="#"
   data-id=""
   data-payload='{"Id":  "@item.Id","projectId": "@item.ProjectId"}'
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#actionConfirmation"
   data-actiontype="approve"
   class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x wfAction">
 </a>
```

and the function I'm calling looks as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".wfAction", function () {

    var sender = $(event.target).attr('id');

    var stepId = $("#approveModal").data("payload").Id;
    var projectId = $("#approveModal").data("payload").projectId;
```

Originally I was passing in #approveModal, when I only had one button, but now I'm trying to assign the click event to the class on the link.  I need to access the individual attributes based on which link sent the request but I'm stuck.

Comment: use the keyword `this` in your click event which would be the `a` that triggered the event. i.e. `$(this).data("payload")` and `var sender = this.id;`

Comment: Make sure to pass in the event to the handler.  Not all browsers make the event a global variable.

Comment: zgood, thank you.  I'd been trying this but I forgot to take the attr of of it.  Been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are binding a click event to an element, when the function is called, the main scope of the function is your element, so if you use `this`, you will be accessing the element itself, that called that function. With that, you just need to get the parameters as you were doing before.

below is an example code based in your original code.

Also, if you intend to use the `event`as you were doing, you need to have it as parameter `function(event){...}`

```js
$(document).on("click", ".wfAction", function () {

    var sender = $(this).attr('id');
    var stepId = $(this).data("payload").Id;
    var projectId = $(this).data("payload").projectId;
    console.log(this);    
    console.log('stepId: ' + stepId + ' | projectId: ' + projectId)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="approveModal" 
   href="#"
   data-id="test1"
   data-payload='{"Id":  "1","projectId": "project one"}'
   class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x wfAction">test 1
 </a>
 <br>
 <a id="approveModal1" 
   href="#"
   data-id="test2"
   data-payload='{"Id":  "2","projectId": "project two"}'
   class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x wfAction">test 2
 </a>
  <br>
 <a id="approveModal2" 
   href="#"
   data-id="test3"
   data-payload='{"Id":  "3","projectId": "project three"}'
   class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x wfAction">test 3
 </a>
```